# 4 rivers of eden

Tags: genesis, creation

A river is a division between two bodies of land by a body of water.

If the rivers were divisions of land, that are most significant, what are they?

So.
By taking this test, I determined, - scientifically - that you can bring 100% of earth's coasts together simultaneously to prove the planet expanded from within itself.

For why does God say these rivers to us? Because, the works of his Creation are Proven by virtue of his methods. And these words are foolproofed encryption that his work is  done.

***Which is pishon? Which is gihon? And where lies the Tigris?***

Comment: Your question lacks clarity and detail. We are left not knowing the details of your 'test'. The above is a thesis regarding expansion but without the proof of the thesis. Please see the Tour and Help regarding the purpose and the functioning of the site. Welcome to BH.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are rivers Gihon and Pishon located, how can we identify them today?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/30770/where-are-rivers-gihon-and-pishon-located-how-can-we-identify-them-today)

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking!!  Are you able to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you’re seeking here with your Q, but here is some background to consider. One of the comments has a link regarding the 4 rivers. And, you need to consider that the earth was very different pre-flood. Some say that there was one single continent, and the flood resulted in the land masses separating ...

**GEN 10:25** *To Eber were born two sons: the name of the one was Peleg, for in his days the earth was divided,*

Peleg ‘place’ in the timeline post flood is found in the next chapter. As well, the flood caused the earth to ‘tilt’, resulting in pronounced seasons. So considering all of the above, the concept of a single coastline would be able to be considered.

Pre-fall Eden was the source for fresh water, which flowed out 4 ways. Although two of the four rivers have counterparts today, that is, are known, it is unlikely that this was their original course - but this is all somewhat speculative. (Although observable [as opposed to theoretical] science confirms much of this.)

Answer (score 0):

Is Eden is where four rivers meet, including the Tigres and Euphrates, why not in the Persian Gulf underwater?  It's the only location that makes sense to me given what we know.

But it's not Biblical Hermeneutics.  Just fun speculation.